# Question on conditional syntax for new col in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to create a new col in a df based on an existing column using a condition. Essentially if the Client Contract Number contains an underscore, I want the value in the new column to be all characters before the underscore, otherwise I want it to be the Client Contract Number with all dashes removed. I'm able to remove the dashes with the below, but the second line doesn't work

```
raw_data_df['Search Text'] = raw_data_df['Client Contract Number'].str.replace('-','')

raw_data_df['Search Text'] = raw_data_df['Client Contract Number'].str.split('_')[0] if raw_data_df['Client Contract Number'].str.contains("_") else raw_data_df['Client Contract Number'].str.replace('-','')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to search for the `_` explicitly, just [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the first part of the string (which is more efficient than `split`) with the `(^[^_]+)` pattern (all characters anchored to the left that are not `_`):

```
raw_data_df['Search Text'] = (raw_data_df['Client Contract Number']
                              .str.extract(r'(^[^_]+)', expand=False)
                              .str.replace('-', '')
                              )
```

Alternatively, a fix of your original approach using a list comprehension. Again, there is no need to explicitly test for the presence of `_` since split would produce the same string if it's absent.

```
raw_data_df['Search Text'] = [s.split('_')[0].replace('-', '') for s in
                              raw_data_df['Client Contract Number']]
```

If really you need to test the presence of `_` to have a different handling of the string (e.g., keep the `-` if there was no underscore), you could do something like:

```
raw_data_df['Search Text'] = [x[0]
                              if len(x:=s.split('_', maxsplit=1) == 1
                              else x[0].replace('-', '')
                              for s in
                              raw_data_df['Client Contract Number']]
```

And with an explicit check (which I believe might be less efficient):

```
raw_data_df['Search Text'] = [s.split('_', maxsplit=1)[0].replace('-', '')
                              if `_` in s else s
                              for s in raw_data_df['Client Contract Number']]
```

Comment: Both worked, thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 1):

Lengthy reply: final answer is in "Answer" subsection.

**Assumptions**

So given the preconditions you listed, it looks like we could have the following client contract numbers:

| Client Contract Number |
| --- |
| 123_2-31 |
| 23-1415 |
| 124-5_259 |
| 1234 |

And given your code and intent, we want the following new dataframe:

| Search Text |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 231415 |
| 1245 |
| 1234 |

(Since we're removing all dashes in your first line of code, I assume the 3rd sample shouldn't contain any dashes whatsoever.)

**Error**

Recreating this dataframe with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Client Contract Number": ["123_2-31", "23-1415", "124-5_259", "1234"] }
raw_data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

We see the following error message pop up when attempting to run our second line of code:

`raw_data_df['Search Text'] = raw_data_df['Client Contract Number'].str.split('_')[0] if raw_data_df['Client Contract Number'].str.contains("_") else raw_data_df['Client Contract Number'].str.replace('-','')`

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I think this has to do with the fact that we're attempting to apply the [ternary conditional](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-operator-in-python/#) on a pandas series. Basically, the conditional is going to try to extract one single truth value on the entire series, hence why pandas asks us to use `a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`.

Also using the `[0]` index in `raw_data_df["Client Contract Number"].str.split("_")[0]` will get us the list that results in splitting the first row of data, instead of the first index of each split row.

**Answer**

I think a good alternative implementation for row-by-row operations would be the [apply method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Essentially, we'll be creating an anonymous function that does the exact same ternary operator, except this time for individual rows

Using your original code as a template, the demo code for this would be as follows:

```
raw_data_df['Search Text'] = raw_data_df['Client Contract Number'].str.replace('-','')
raw_data_df["Search Text"] = raw_data_df["Search Text"].apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[0] if "_" in x else x)
```

This should produce the second dataframe you're hopefully looking for. Since you're already removing dashes in your first line, there's no need to reiterate this in your second line of code.

Hope it helps! You may have to tweak this code if the initial assumptions I listed out aren't accurate.